# how to add item to list retrived by LINQ

Tags: c#

I have the following list

```
 var listOfParks = (from s in DB.MasterDatas

                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = s.service_under,

                           }).Distinct().Union(
                           from t in DB.MasterDatas
                            join f in DB.Users1
                           on t.pv_person_resp_id equals f.user_id     
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = f.user_name

                           }).ToList()
```

But I need to add manually "All" to this list,i am trying this:

```
    var listOfParks = (from s in DB.MasterDatas

                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = s.service_under,

                           }).Distinct().Union(
                           from t in DB.MasterDatas
                            join f in DB.Users1
                           on t.pv_person_resp_id equals f.user_id     
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = f.user_name

                           }).ToList().Add(new SelectListItem{Text="All"});
```

but I get error:Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

Comment: Just put it in a separate line, the issue is `.Add` returns `void` and it is trying to assign that to `listOfParks`. Just put it on the next line.

Comment: `.Concat(new SelectListItem{Text="All"}).ToList();` using https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#concat

Comment: Also, remove the `Distinct()` - it isn't needed. `Union` will do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `.Add` it on the next line, you can't do an add in one line with LINQ:

```
var listOfParks = (from s in DB.MasterDatas

                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = s.service_under,

                           }).Distinct().Union(
                           from t in DB.MasterDatas
                            join f in DB.Users1
                           on t.pv_person_resp_id equals f.user_id     
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = f.user_name

                           }).ToList();
listOfParks.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="All"});
```

The issue is that `.Add` returns `void` which it is trying to assign to `listOfParks` which it cannot. Or you can use `.Concat` but really there is no reason you can't have it on a separate line for clarity.